# dpkg-query vs apt-cache

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I noticed an interesting phenomenon and I am looking for an explanation. On my Ubuntu system, `dpkg-query` cannot find some uninstalled packages which `apt-cache` can find. For instance,

```
dpkg-query -l libssl-dev
```

gives me:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libssl-dev
```

while:

```
apt-cache show libssl-dev
```

finds the package information. At the same time, `dpkg-query` can locate other uninstalled packages, e.g. gimp and show their status as uninstalled. Why are some packages not visible to `dpkg-query`?

Comment: What does `dpkg-query -f '${db:Status-Abbrev}\t${Package}\n' --show gimp libssl-dev` say?

Comment: `un      gimp
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libssl-dev`, so again, gimp is found, and libssl-dev is not.

Comment: Uninstalled != purged: you've probably installed Gimp before and later uninstalled (but not purged) it, so its configuration files remain on your computer. On the other hand, libssl-dev has either never been installed or completely removed (with `apt-get remove --purge`), so there are no indications of its existence left that dpkg could find.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. The problem occurs on a clean system before gimp was installed. It also occurs after installing libssl-dev and then uninstalling it (not purging) using apt-get remove libssl-dev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, `dpkg-query` shows you what is installed on your system, or even packages which has been installed on your system and then been removed at some point.

Interestingly enough, if a package uses a dependency of another package, `dpkg` may list them as installed even though one of them was never fully installed on the system.

But `apt` is used to download packages from the repositories defined in your sources.list and sources.d/* directory.

in other words, `apt-cache` shows the packages that "could be installed" on your system not the ones already installed/uninstalled.

Comment: I don't think that is the answer. As I said in my question, gimp not being installed, is still found by dpkg-query and reported as not installed. So dpkg-query is aware of not installed packages.

Comment: if you've installed gimp in some point, it will be listed in `dpkg`. But if you've never installed gimp on your machine, maybe another package used Gimp's libraries as a dependency and that's why you see it in `dpkg`

Comment: That seems to be the case indeed. I looked up reverse dependencies of gimp and libssl-dev and there is one package that suggests gimp that is installed, while no installed packages list as dependency libssl-dev.  Would be great if you could add your comment to your answer for anyone who runs into my problem in the future.

Comment: would be nice to mark the answer as the correct one, too. So anyone who runs into the problem know the correct answer :)

Comment: you are most welcome