# Distinction between apt-cache and dpkg -l

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I use apt-cache pkgname to retrieve the packages as

```
me@host:~$ apt-cache pkgnames | wc -l
62803
```

get 62803 results

but

```
me@host:~$ dpkg -l | wc -l
2336
```

What's the reasons which lead such a huge distinction. I presume that dpkg is super than apt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg-query vs apt-cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655555/dpkg-query-vs-apt-cache)

Comment: @Olorin I voted to Leave this question Open. They're duplicates alright, but I want the direction of the duplication to be reversed and [dpkg-query vs apt-cache](https://askubuntu.com/q/655555/) to be closed as a duplicate of this question instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`apt` is for managing remote repositories, `dpkg` - for locally installed packages. They're related. `apt` is front end to `dpkg`. When you run `apt-get install package` it gets `.deb` file, and installs it via `dpkg`. So numbers differ because there's a lot of packages available, but only fraction is installed locally on your system.

`apt-cache` can show both installed and non-installed packages, because it queries the `apt` cache - listing of what is available in remote repositories ( that cache is what you get when you do `apt-get update`). For instance,

```
$ apt-cache policy terminator
terminator:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.91-1


$ dpkg -l terminator
dpkg-query: no packages found matching terminator
```

---

Note that there is another tool which can query list of installed/removed local packages, and that's [`dpkg-query`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg-query.1.html). For instance,

```
$ dpkg-query -l 'libc6'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                 Version         Architecture    Description
+++-====================-===============-===============-=============================================
ii  libc6:amd64          2.27-3          amd64           GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386           2.27-3          i386            GNU C Library: Shared libraries

$ dpkg -l libc6
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                 Version         Architecture    Description
+++-====================-===============-===============-=============================================
ii  libc6:amd64          2.27-3          amd64           GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6:i386           2.27-3          i386            GNU C Library: Shared libraries
```

As per [dpkg manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg.1.html)

> dpkg can also be used as a front-end to dpkg-deb(1) and dpkg-query(1). The list  of  supported actions  can  be found later on in the ACTIONS section. If any such action is encountered dpkg just runs dpkg-deb or dpkg-query with the parameters given to it, but no specific options  are currently passed to them, to use any such option the back-ends need to be called directly.

As far as `dpkg-query` goes, it should be noted that this tool is focused on querying the database of installed packages, and can output information in particular format(`-f` option plus `-W` action). For instance,

```
$ dpkg-query -W -f='PACK:${Package}\nARCH:${Architecture}\nSTAT:${Status}\n---\n' libc6
PACK:libc6
ARCH:amd64
STAT:install ok installed
---
PACK:libc6
ARCH:i386
STAT:install ok installed
---
```

Interestingly enough, dpkg database maintains listing of packages that are [selected for removal](https://askubuntu.com/a/165961/295286) or [were removed at some point](https://askubuntu.com/a/655568/295286). `dpkg-query` can also take glob pattern as an argument, and [depending on presence of absence of it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/344860/85039) show only installed/configured packages or all packages.

Answer (score 3):

dpkg -l shows your installed package versions (starting with ii), removed ones (rc), and some others (e.g. installed but not configured, see the manpage).

apt-cache pkgnames shows you all the available package names (but not versions of the same package) in the added repositories.